# Difference Between a Time-Domain and a Simulation Domain Acoustic Pressure Simulation

Tags: acoustics, computational-physics, simulations, signal-processing

I would appreciate it if someone would be able to clarify my doubts. I'm currently working on acoustic simulations in COMSOL and is currently confused on the information provided by the simulations results. I apologies if this question is lengthy but I believe the following example properly encapsulates my problem.

Suppose that I have a 1-D system, where the left boundary vibrating harmonically (arbitrary Dirichlet pressure of 1 bar) at a frequency of 20 kHz, while the right boundary is specified as an infinitely hard boundary. I performed 2 simulations, 1 using the wave equation in the time-domain, while the other using the Helmholtz equation in the frequency-domain.

As the length of the simulated domain is set to 0.225 m or exactly 3 wavelengths (assuming constant density and phase speed in water), I expect the wave to travel from left-to-right, reflect at the infinitely hard boundary, and form a standing wave at steady state. Since there is no explicit specification of attenuation, I also expected the possibility that the antinodes would have infinite magnitude due to the harmonic loading.

However, as I analyzed the results I am rather perplex by a number of observations. Firstly, since the system is monoharmonic in nature, I expected the frequency-domain solution to give the same or at least similar results to the time-domain counterpart. However, this does not seem to be the case. To properly illustrate my confusion over this matter, shown below is the plot of acoustic pressure from the frequency-domain solution.

[image: Acoustic pressure plot from the frequency-domain simulation]

The solution makes sense as it does have 3 wavelengths, with the nodes and antinodes of standing wave clearly defined. What confused me pertains to the results of the time domain simulation. I simulated the system for 100 cycles to compare the 'steady-state' of the transient simulation with the frequency domain. However, the results showed an unexpected outcome. Shown below is the plot of all the pressure profiles for the 1000 time frames (10 data frames per cycle) in which data is extracted from the simulation. [image: All 1000 frames of pressure profiles for the transient simulation results]

It can be clearly seen that instead of the formation of a steady-state standing wave in the transient simulation, there seems to be multiple "modes" of standing waves, despite the system being specified to be monoharmonic in nature. I have further analyzed the time-domain results frame-by-frame and indeed confirmed that instead of starting with some transients and achieving a standing wave steady state, the system instead shows a periodic behavior transitioning between a 'standing wave', a travelling wave, and even a state where the reflected wave almost fully cancels the incident wave. I have checked and confirmed that I have specified the boundary conditions correctly, including checking the harmonic pressure boundary for the time-domain.

So henceforth I present my questions:

1. Is my understanding of the frequency domain solution wrong? Or is there other unaccounted errors from the time-domain simulations that caused this?
2. If this discrepancy is indeed from simulation errors, how should I approach it? I have tried refining the mesh and explicitly reducing the time-steps but it seems that there is still a degree of numerical dispersion. There is also the fact that the pressure magnitudes were also different in both cases.
3. Does a system that do not form a steady-state "standing wave" have a solution when simulated in the frequency domain? If so, what does the frequency domain solution mean?

I apologize if I did not word my question properly. If any additional information is required, such as animation files of the evolution of the time-domain simulation, please do say so.

Comment: Without being a numerical simulations experet, I believe your main issue here is dispersion. Not sure how fine is your grid to minimise such errors. Have you tried running the simulation with lower frequencies to see if there's any sight of convergence towards a common solution? Finding different magnitudes for different time-steps does make sense to me as this should be a product of numerical dispersion in the time domain (under-sampling in the temporal dimension)

Comment: Hello, thanks you very much for your input! I have refined the mesh but the results did not change significantly. However, trying out a much smaller solver time-stepping indeed show promising convergence!

Comment: I guess the main issue then was the "temporal mesh". If you manage to get the results you want it may also be instructive and helpful to people that may have the same problems with you in the future to provide an answer to your own question.

Comment: I just wanted to provide a small update with regards to the above problems. Anyone who is wondering about the changing 'modes' in the transient simulation could refer to a previously discussed question which is similar: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445625/